# Im confused with Least Squares Regression Derivation (Linear Algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, matlab, least-squares

I am having troubles understanding Least Squares Regression Derivation (Linear Algebra) in order to code it in matlab. As far as I have understood, is that you take the residual value = (yhat - y)^2 . But in order to find yhat = summnation of the data point alpha *function(x). Hence in order to find the alpha which is the parameter, I need to sum the residual values? I don’t understand this part. Also it says there are more data points than basis functions which I don’t get. I am trying to learn from the SB matlab book.

The book also states “from observation, the vector in the range of A,Yˆ, that is closest to Y is the one that can point perpendicularly to Y . Therefore, we want a vector Y − Yˆ that is perpendicular to the vector Yˆ. “What does it mean by observation? Like how is it mathematically true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sum the *expression* involving
the residual values.
This expression involves
the alpha that 
you want to find
the value of.

Taking the derivative of this expression
with respect to alpha
and setting that to zero
gives you an equation
that determines alpha.

{in response to OP's question)

Simple case:
Fit $ax+b$ to a set of $y$ values.

Residual at
$(x_i, y_i)$
is
$ax_i+b - y_i$.

Sum of squares of residuals is
$D
=\sum_{i=1}^n (ax_i+b-y_i)^2
$.

Take derivative with respect to
each parameter.
Note that
$\frac{\partial f^2(g(x))}{\partial x}
=2g'(x)f'(g(x))
$.

$D_a
=\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_i(ax_i+b-y_i)
=2a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2+2b\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-2\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i
$.

$D_b
=\sum_{i=1}^n 2(ax_i+b-y_i)
=2a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i+2b\sum_{i=1}^n1-2\sum_{i=1}^ny_i
$.

Set these equal to zero
and solve for $a$ and $b$.

Simpler case:
Fit $ax$ to a set of $y$ values.
This is a line through the origin.

Residual at
$(x_i, y_i)$
is
$ax_i - y_i$.

Sum of squares of residuals is
$D
=\sum_{i=1}^n (ax_i-y_i)^2
$.

Take derivative with respect to
the parameter.

$D_a
=\sum_{i=1}^n 2x_i(ax_i-y_i)
=2a\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-2\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i
$.

Equating this to zero,
$a
=\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}
$

Comment: hey thanks for the reply! I was looking towards solving it the linear algebra way but I don't mind exploring it the calculus way. Do you mind explaining ur answer further because I am still confused where u said "taking the derivative of this expression with respect the alpha" Thank you thank you!

Comment: Thank you. I got a similar equation: mean(xy) - mean(x)*mean(y) / mean(x^2) - (mean(x))^2. This is great. I am still stuck on what does a basis function actually mean? why are there more data point m than basis function? Aren't there suppose to be equal amount of data points as to the data from the equation yhat = alphaX + b?

Comment: No. There can be an arbitrarily large number of data points. Also, just divide the sums by the number of data points to get the means.